# What is the song during Neo's "Follow the White Rabbit" scene

Tags: the-matrix, music

[image: Neo asleep at his desk. Scene is about 29 minutes in]

What is the song that he turns off, the minute he see's "Wake Up Neo" on it.

Where can I find it? I have the OST of the three movies, and fan made similar tastes. But I wan't to get my hands on as much of the films songs as I can. Would boot up the film and watch credits like I did for Animatrix, but my PC isn't running DVD's for some strange reason

Comment: A question like this should be posted on the exchange dedicated to Movies and TV.

http://movies.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Questions like these usually get closed on M&TV as trivia, but I would agree it would be better suited there.

Comment: @Daft - Given that it's not on the OST, I'm happy to leave it up. It's trivia but not trivial.

Comment: @Richard plus if the answer is Massive Attack, it trumps all rules and deserves to be left up!

Comment: Related sister site question about [the search software running on Neo’s computer in this scene](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7255/60 "
Software Recommendations: Search tool that shows/scrolls the documents it searches (like the tool from The Matrix)").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is "Dissolved Girl" by Massive Attack

[image]

Comment: man im a noob. How do you do this so fast?!

Comment: @Sidhartha Google

Comment: @Sidhartha - Well, I identified the song by opening the film and listening to the lyrics. I then googled them and found the answer to the question. That led me to youtube where I found the link to the song. I took a screenshot of the end of the film for completeness and copied the whole lot into the answer box as I went along.

Comment: @Sidhartha it's actually mentioned on the [wiki page for the music from the movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Matrix:_Music_from_the_Motion_Picture). : _The music playing on Neo's headphones ("Dissolved Girl" by Massive Attack) when he is contacted by Trinity._ It's always worth doing a bit of Googling before posting a question.